# pynput keyboard listener function variable pass

Tags: python, pynput

I am having an issue of passing the count variable over to the on_press function that is being called for every key press using the pynput listener library. I am confused as to why the variable is not being incremented then output to the screen. It does increment and output on the first iteration but not on the next. I am confused pls help.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import string

count = 0 

def on_press(count):
    count += 1
    print(count)

with Listener(on_press=on_press(count)) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here surrounds the topic of variable scope. The `count` variable being referenced inside `on_press` is the `count` argument being passed into the function (**not the global** variable `count` defined outside the function). Integers in Python are passed by copy to function (not by reference). So what's happening in your code is that you are making a copy of the global variable `count`, passing that into `on_press`, and then `on_press` only increments the local copy of `count` passed in - hence it will always print out 1.

If you want count to be incremented each time on_press is called, you should directly increment the global count variable as follows:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import string

count = 0 

def on_press():
    global count
    count += 1
    print(count)

with Listener(on_press=on_press()) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Using this method of declaring the global count inside the function and incrementing it does the exact same thing as before with only printing 1 and not printing anything else. I tried fiddling around with it also and nothing seems to be working